# Extracting a part of the list based on a criteria

Tags: python, list

```
lst = [[2,'UNIT'], [5,'TEN'], [8,'HUNDRED'], [7, 'THOUSAND'], [8, 'THOUSAND'], [9,'LAKH'], 
       [6, 'LAKH'], [4, 'CRORE'], [2, 'CRORE'], [3, 'CRORE']]
```

I have 10 lists inside list named `lst`.

I want to iterate through the list using a `for` loop for all the list with a specific value, say `CRORE`, instead of the entire list.

Comment: What so ever tried you and what error did you get mention that too!

Comment: I have mentioned two methods you can check out... both will work same.

Answer (score 2):

This might help. I have written the code below:

```
lst = [[2,'UNIT'], [5,'TEN'], [8,'HUNDRED'], [7, 'THOUSAND'], [8, 'THOUSAND'],
       [9,'LAKH'], [6, 'LAKH'], [4, 'CRORE'], [2, 'CRORE'], [3, 'CRORE']]

for x in lst:
    for y in x:
        if y=="CRORE":
            print(x)
```

Here `x` represents all the sublists inside your list i.e `lst`,
and `y` represents the values inside the sublists i.e integers or strings.

Also this can be done using list comprehension as mentioned below
in this you will get a new list with the values of `CRORE` only.

```
lst = [[2,'UNIT'], [5,'TEN'], [8,'HUNDRED'], [7, 'THOUSAND'], [8, 'THOUSAND'],
       [9,'LAKH'], [6, 'LAKH'], [4, 'CRORE'], [2, 'CRORE'], [3, 'CRORE']]

newlst = [x for x in lst if x[1] == 'CRORE']
print(newlst)
```

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to filter the `list of list` based on the value at index 1:

```
filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == 'CRORE', lst))
filtered_list = [i for i in lst if i[1] == 'CRORE']
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate thorugh your list and it contains 2 elements in list so get second position and use if conditon and create another list and append data to it

```
lst = [[2,'UNIT'], [5,'TEN'], [8,'HUNDRED'], [7, 'THOUSAND'], [8, 'THOUSAND'], [9,'LAKH'], [6, 'LAKH'], [4, 'CRORE'], [2, 'CRORE'], [3, 'CRORE']]
lst1=[]
for i,j in lst:
    if j=='CRORE':
        lst1.append([i,j])
```

in one line answer for list comprehension

```
lst1=[[i,j] for i,j in lst if j=="CRORE"]
```

Output:

```
[[4, 'CRORE'], [2, 'CRORE'], [3, 'CRORE']]
```